# Remote desktop: automatically logoff when disconnected

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, remote-desktop, logoff

I'm using Windows' Remote Desktop to connect from a Windows 7 machine to a Windows XP one. Many times, I just hit 'X' on the window without logging off when I'm finished using it, and subsequent users on the remote machine can't login because I'm still logged in to the Administrator account (user switching is disabled and must stay that way).

Reference:

[image]

Is there any way that I can set it up so that when RDP is disconnected from the remote machine, the remote session is logged off automatically?

(I thought about using a script on the remote machine to log off whenever the RDP is disconnected, but I can't see how to detect that; there doesn't seem to be any event associated with it.)

Edit: As stijn suggested, I tried using [this batch file](http://www.sumoc.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/3/10/How-to-autologoff-remote-Desktop-Users#comment-8214405C-5056-03DC-A580913F241B259F) to query the remote computer for disconnected users with `quser` and then logging them off with `rwinsta`. However it seems that these commands are specifically for Windows Server editions.

Comment: batchfile found here should be usable, maybe with some tweaks: http://www.sumoc.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/3/10/How-to-autologoff-remote-Desktop-Users

Comment: and http://superuser.com/questions/399962/how-can-i-make-sure-that-users-log-out-of-remote-desktop-sessions-instead-of-jus

Comment: @stijn I actually found that before I posted, but for some reason I always get "Access is Denied" and I can't figure out why....

Comment: "Acces id Denied" on what? maybe you should add that to the question as well

Comment: @stijn For the Quser command.

Answer (score 3):

You could [set a time limit for disconnected sessions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791741). This isn't exactly what you asked for, but if you set a low time limit, it achieves a substantially similar result.

Comment: I don't see how this works if I don't have Windows Server 2008.

Comment: @HodofHod The option is available in Windows 7 as well, in the same location.  It is also in Windows XP, but in a slightly different location.  The tool to set it, `gpedit.msc` may not be available in all editions however.

Comment: Ah, I found it. It was the "\Policies\" that threw me off...